# sed command to replace the first line of a file if it starts with "//------"

Tags: text-processing, sed

The idea is:

if the first line of the file FILE.txt starts with

```
//-----------
```

replace it with

```
//----------- %TAG
```

To do it I used the following command

```
sed -i "1s/.\/\/-----------/& %TAG/" FILE.txt
```

But it didn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Would you try with a space: `1 s/...` because as far as I know you need a space between the address (line number) and the command (`s/`).

Answer (score 3):

you are so close: just drop the `.` You are saying starts with some character then // …

`sed -i "1s/\/\/-----------/& %TAG/" FILE.txt`

or change the delimiter to reduce escaping.

`sed -i "1s#//-----------#& %TAG#" FILE.txt`

Comment: And make it `^//-----------` to only match at the start of the line. (Or something like `^//-----*` if you don't want to be picky about the number of dashes.)

Comment: I see you are new to the site. If you like an answer then click the tick ✓.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. The dot at the beginning will match any character, that seems that is not needed. And to make the string match only at the start of the line the regex should start with a `^`:

```
sed -i "1s#^//-----------#& %TAG#" file.txt
```

Using a `#` as the `s` command delimiter simplify the back-quoting.